# CakePHP - Twitter Component

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, oauth, components

I'm trying to make a Twitter component for CakePHP so I can sign in with Twitter and eventually allow my users to post to Twitter as well, this is my component:

```
<?php

class TwitterHelperComponent extends Object {
    var $name = 'TwitterHelper';
    var $twitterObj;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        require_once(APP.'vendors/twitter/EpiCurl.php');
        require_once(APP.'vendors/twitter/EpiOAuth.php');
        require_once(APP.'vendors/twitter/EpiTwitter.php');

        $this->twitterObj = new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    } 

    function setOAuthToken($oauth_token) {
        $this->twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token);
        $token = $this->twitterObj->getAccessToken();
        $this->twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);

        return $twitter;
    }
}
?>
```

And in my bootstrap.php file I placed the following:

```
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY', '*******');
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET', '********');
```

In my controller I set the twitterObj to the view:

```
function home(){
        $this->layout = 'home';
        $this->set('twitter', $this->TwitterHelper->twitterObj);
    }
```

And in my view I do the following:

```
<a class='twitter-button' href='<?php echo $twitter->getAuthenticateUrl(); ?>'></a>
```

But I just get an undefined variable warning in my view for `twitterObj`. I'm using [this](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) Twitter PHP lib:

Also, my whole interface just goes out of whack and it loses all the styles when I try to get the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just retrieving the URL in your controller, and passing that through the set. I'm not sure passing an object reference will work as you intend.

Comment: The problems seems to be that the twitterObj is not getting instantiated because I get Call to a member function getAuthenticateUrl() on a non-object error

Comment: Not sure why that would happen. If you're not getting any other errors, you're not calling what you think you're calling, since the code I'm seeing above should instantiate that.

Comment: Ok, I took out the __contruct function and made a function that would just instantiate the twitterObj and I got class EpiTwitter not defined, seems like the constructor wasn't doing anything and at all and after that the App::import wasn't doing anything either because I replaced the App::imports with require_once and it worked, well, it worked as in I have a URL now

Comment: Any idea what could've happened with the constructor?

Comment: You might want to check the spelling on it, actually, now that I look closer.

Comment: @8vius let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2247/discussion-between-utoxin-and-8vius)